# Batch script - split a string with parenthesis

Tags: string, batch-file, split, cmd

In a Windows batch script, I need to split a string which contains user names and userIDs in parenthesis and possibly non-employee status in parenthesis, to a comma-separated list of userIDs only.

SET INPUT=Stone, Jake (non-empl) (stonej), Smith, John (smithj), Doe Milton, Jane (doej)

OUTPUT=stonej,smithj,doej

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: What is the significance of `non-empl`, I assume you expect the script to filter out any content that says `non-empl`?

Comment: non-empl indicates non-employee status and should be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the task - but it will change if the actual task is to convert a file.
This should handle characters that plain batch code will have problems with.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
set "input=Stone, Jake (non-empl) (stonej), Smith, John (smithj), Doe Milton, Jane (doej)"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo "%input%,"^|repl "\(non-empl\)" "" ^|repl ".*?\((.*?)\).*?," "$1," ^|repl "..$" "" ') do set output=%%a
echo "%output%"
pause
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I have to look into the details of repl.bat, but it works. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just out of curiosity...can the above be achieved without repl.bat? How do I "extract" whatever is in parenthesis only not knowing the token number for an infinite string, while ignoring (non-empl)?

Comment: Yes it can, but it won't be as robust and will be a larger script.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

SET INPUT=Stone, Jake (non-empl) (stonej), Smith, John (smithj), Doe Milton, Jane (doej)

for /F "tokens=4,6,8 delims=()" %%a in ("%input%") do set OUTPUT=%%a,%%b,%%c
echo OUTPUT=%OUTPUT%
```

Output:

```
OUTPUT=stonej,smithj,doej
```

Comment: Thank you Aacini. This works only for above example. However, the INPUT example line was just a representation...in reality, it could contain up to a 100 names and corresponding IDs. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native batch-file solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "input=Stone, Jake (non-empl) (stonej), Smith, John (smithj), Doe Milton, Jane (doej)"

:: Define LF to contain a linefeed character
set ^"LF=^

^" Above empty line is critical - DO NOT REMOVE

:: Remove (non-empl) from data
set "input=!input:(non-empl)=!"

:: insert linefeed before ( and after )
for %%L in ("!LF!") do (
  set "input=!input:(=%%~L(!"
  set "input=!input:)=)%%~L!"
)

:: Echo the value and pipe to FINDSTR to preserve lines containing (
:: Must delay expansion by escaping !, and use CMD /V:ON to re-enable delayed expansion
:: Use FOR /F to parse the result, discarding ( and ), and build output
for /f "delims=()" %%A in ('cmd /v:on /c echo ^^!input^^!^|findstr "("') do set output=!output!%%A,

:: Remove unwanted trailing , from output
set "output=!output:~0,-1!"

:: Show result
echo output=!output!
```